# C++ class member allocation

Tags: c++, class, memory-management

Assume I have this:

```
class foo{
    Member member;
    foo();
    ~foo();
};
```

How I should allocate the member?

**EDIT: How should I tell him which constructor to use?(sorry for being unclear)**

*Now I already know about the `member = Member(...);` syntax*

Will this cause memory leak?

```
{
    Memory *temp = new Member();
    member = *(temp);   //will it work at all??(is it copy constructor?)
    delete temp;
}
```

Comment: I've already found that I should use memory = Member(); without the new.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ is not Java. This member is already allocated. It is part of the memory of the instance it is in. It will get constructed (initialized) by the constructor of the containing instance. The key word new has nothing to do with a member that is not a pointer.

Comment: It is worth noting that the pattern used where a Member is allocated on the heap and then assigned to member could in fact result in a memory leak.  If the copy-assignment operator throws an exception, it will leak `temp`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Member` is not a typedef for a pointer type, i.e. it's *not* defined as, say,

```
typedef int* Member;
```

you don't have to do anything to allocate it as it is automatically allocated when you allocate instances of `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: How should I tell him which constructor to use?(sorry for being unclear)

like this:

```
foo::foo() : member(...) // member initializer list
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How should I tell him which constructor to use?

`Member member` in class declaration is not calling any constructor yet as it is just declaration. However, when you define it later on you should use `member()`, `member` or `member(arg,..)` to define the member object and calling a certain constructor.

The code is fine and it works. Just note that it will call the assignment operator and not the copy constructor.